# How align many figures in a single figure?

Tags: graphics, positioning

I am trying to build a single image with multiple subimages but the problem is I want the image in this below given format and I don't know how:

[image]

Comment: easy with tikz.

Answer (score 1):

Without more specifications, two `minipage`s are enough:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=.3\textheight]{example-image-16x9}\\[1em]
\begin{minipage}[c]{.3\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\[1em]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}\\[1em]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}\\[1em]
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.6\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```